# Why does USB3 cable work with Pi 2, but not Pi 3?

Tags: pi-2, pi-3, usb3

I have two PIs: Pi 2 Model B v1.1, and Pi 3 Model B.

Both Pis are running with defaults. Also, both Pis are each powered by a 2A supply.

I also have an externally powered hard drive dock that happens to be USB 3.0. I understand that neither of my Pis have USB 3.0 support, that's not the issue.

I discovered that if I plug the dock into the Pi 3 using a USB 3 cable, the drive is not recognized by the Pi (no new device shows up in dmesg or lsusb).

However, if I plug the dock into my Pi 2, even with the USB 3 cable, it is recognized and I can even mount/access the drive.

Since I needed the disk to be mounted on the Pi 3, I was able to mount the drive by instead using a USB 2.0 cable.

**The question:** Why would the USB 3 cable work with the Pi 2, but not the Pi 3?

Comment: There is no logical reason. A USB3 cable has 9 pins, the 4 standard USB2 pins plus 5 others. The Pi2/3 USB **ONLY** has the matching 4 pins, so either cable should work.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, there is no easy logical explanation right off the bat. Both the RPi2 and RPi3 use the same USB controller (LAN9514, [see here](http://elinux.org/RPi_Hardware)). Unless there are material differences between the actual USB ports between the RPi2 and RPi3 (which I doubt), this may be an OS issue.

Which OS's are you running on both?

Comment: Both Pis are running Raspbian 8. The Pi 3 has kernel 4.4.38-v7+, and the Pi 2 has kernel 4.1.13-v7+.